# redirect seems not to work in Suave

Tags: f#, suave

I tried redirecting to an index.html page with  path "/hello" >>= redirect "index.html" and it keeps giving the error No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: Do you also have a handler defined for "index.cshtml"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with redirection in Suave. The following works fine for me:

```
#r @"packages/Suave/lib/net40/Suave.dll"
open Suave
open Suave.Web
open Suave.Http
open Suave.Http.Applicatives

choose
  [ path "/index.html" >>= Successful.OK "Hello" 
    path "/redir" >>= Redirection.redirect "/index.html" ]
|> startWebServer defaultConfig
```

As Fyodor mentioned in the comments, I'd check if your handler for `index.html` is working correctly. You can also check the returned redirect header in Fiddler or in Chrome dev tools.